# For each unique value in a column, count respective unique values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a set of tabular data (e.g. csv) representing accesses to a server through a specific protocol . The data follows this format:

```
server_id | protocol
===================
    s1         A
    s1         C
    s1         C
    s1         B
    s2         A
    s2         B
    s2         C
    s2         A
    s3         A
    s3         B
    s3         B
```

`server_id` can be one of: `s1, s2, s3`
`protocol` can be one of: `A, B, C`

In R, how can I get the following?

```
server_id | A | B | C
=====================
    s1      1   1   2
    s2      2   1   1
    s3      1   2   0
```

A, B and C columns represent the amount of times a server was accessed with that protocol.

I cannot wrap my head around the declarative way of doing things in R and need some help.
Let me know if my question is not clear or if this is not the correct place to post it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is more of a programming question than a data science question it would be better suited for the stackoverflow stackexchange page, but this can done relatively easily using some of the functions from the `tidyr` library:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  server_id = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3"),
  protocol = c("A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B")
)

df %>%
  # count number of rows for each combination of server_id and protocol
  group_by(server_id, protocol) %>%
  tally() %>%
  # pivot the protocol names over the columns
  pivot_wider(names_from=protocol, values_from=n) %>%
  # replace NA values in all columns with 0
  mutate(across(everything(), .fns=~replace_na(., 0)))
```

Which returns the following dataframe:

| server_id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| s2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| s3 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to be it!
In the future I'll make sure to ask this sort of questions there .